# From WEBrick to Apache2 & Passenger, got ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, controller, passenger

I just changed in my local development laptop from WEBrick to Apache2/Passenger.  Now I got

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#create
```

I'm using
Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 2.3.8
ubuntu 10.04

I tried both

```
protect_from_forgery, :only => [:update, :delete, :create]
```

and

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

in my applicaiton_controller.rb

They didn't seem to help.  (BTW, should I have restarted Passenger somehow after modifying applicaiton_controller.rb?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to restart apache after changing your application.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the default Passenger setup, it runs your application in the production environment - this usually means class caching is turned on.  You'll need to restart your Passenger worker when you make config or code changes like the ones you described via:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Additionally, you can switch your Passenger configuration to run in Development environment via the following Passenger config:

```
RailsEnv development
```

Comment: Thanks, Winfield. 

I finally deicde to give up on Apache2 and go with nginx / Passenger intead.  That has beening working for me so far.